# Convert bitmap to png image and save in database

Tags: c#, image

I have a bitmap image. I want to compress it into a png image so that it will consume less memory while saving it in database.

During my research, I get lot of options to save it as a file in hard disk. I want to return the png image from a method.

Comment: Assuming you want a byte[] for the database. I cant remember the save methods off the top of my head for BitmapImage, You could save the file to disk as a PNG, read that file as a byte[], then immediately delete the hard image.

Comment: You should mention what kind of Database you're referring to. There are quite different options and outcomes when treating a binary for storage, depending on the database technology.

Answer (score 1):

To get png byte array from png source

```
public byte[] GetPng(string filename)
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(filename))
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

With Dapper ORM

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Images]([FullName], [Data]) VALUES (@FullName, @Data)";
var result = db.Execute(sql, new
{
    FullName = filename,
    Data = GetPng(filename)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I currently read the touch screen for the signature and save the image as bitmap in my code and save it in database as byteArray[]. Will it take less memory to save as a png byteArray rather than bitmap byteArray[] ? if so, I want to convert bitmap image to png image in the code and then save it in the database. I do not want to save the image in disk.

Comment: BMP is both uncompressed and lossless and PNG is compressed but lossless - yes, it will take less space. Instead of saving the PNG to a file I showed how to store it in a stream, convert it to byte array and store it in database. Instead of passing BMP file name and reading it from the disk you can just pass the BMP class object.

Comment: Additionally, I should point out that stackoverflow questions should show some effort - what have you tried, why did it fail, set constraints like database schema and ex: ORM/database you are using. My goal is not to give you a working solution, but help you where you are stuck.